# Remove duplicate dates based on a separate column

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

The head of my data looks like:

```
     IndID Event       Date
148   P01     1 2011-03-04
147   P01     1 2011-03-11
149   P01     0 2011-03-13
150   P01     0 2011-03-14
151   P01     0 2011-03-14
152   P01     0 2011-03-14
```

There are 3 individuals (P01, P03, P06).
"Event" specifies whether an event occurred (0=no, 1=yes)
"Date" is the monitoring date.

My goal is to remove duplicate dates based on the Event column for each individual.  Where duplicates exist and no Event has occurred (all Event values are 0 for a given Date), then duplicates should be removed and Event should remain 0.  When duplicate dates are present and there has been an Event (meaning at least one of the Event values is 1), then I am trying to removing duplicates and leave a single row for the given date with 1 in the Event column.

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544128/removing-duplicate-dates-based-on-another-column-in-r)  post was useful, I am looking for more specifics.  Currently I am struggling with a nested `for()` loop that is likely overly complicated and not necessary.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  My data is below:

If it is relevant, once I have a single Date for each individual, I then hope to add the dates that are missing by merging a sequence (from the first to the last date of each individual) with my existing data and add a 0 within the Event column to the new entries.

```
DP <- structure(list(IndID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("P01", "P02", "P03", "P05", "P06", "P07", 
"P08", "P09", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P13"), class = "factor"), 
    Event = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L
    ), Date = structure(c(1299196800, 1299801600, 1299974400, 
    1300060800, 1300060800, 1300060800, 1300147200, 1300320000, 
    1300406400, 1300406400, 1300492800, 1300492800, 1300665600, 
    1300924800, 1301097600, 1302048000, 1302134400, 1302220800, 
    1302652800, 1302825600, 1302998400, 1303084800, 1303171200, 
    1303257600, 1303689600, 1303862400, 1304208000, 1304380800, 
    1304553600, 1304640000, 1305072000, 1305590400, 1305676800, 
    1305676800, 1305676800, 1305763200, 1305936000, 1306022400, 
    1306022400, 1306108800, 1306368000, 1323129600, 1323388800, 
    1323648000, 1323993600, 1324080000, 1324166400, 1324339200, 
    1327622400, 1327622400, 1327795200, 1327881600, 1327881600, 
    1328486400, 1328659200, 1328832000, 1329177600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("IndID", "Event", 
"Date"), row.names = c(148L, 147L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 
51L, 52L, 154L, 53L, 155L, 145L, 156L, 157L, 373L, 382L, 384L, 
361L, 385L, 349L, 387L, 386L, 388L, 341L, 360L, 339L, 334L, 366L, 
340L, 363L, 352L, 351L, 353L, 355L, 397L, 336L, 337L, 354L, 335L, 
371L, 475L, 417L, 472L, 492L, 494L, 493L, 473L, 468L, 497L, 495L, 
486L, 499L, 470L, 487L, 496L, 469L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you're not so much removing duplicates are you are simply aggregating. It sounds like you just want the maximum Event value for each date for each individual (either 1 if there was an event or 0 if not).

```
aggregate(Event~Date+IndID, DP, max)
```

That should do the trick. If you have other columns of data to keep track of as well, try this method

```
inddate <- with(DP, ave(Event, Date, IndID, 
    FUN=function(x)seq_along(x)==which.max(x)))
DP[inddate==1, ]
```

Comment: Your suggestions are much appreciated and spot on.  Indeed, simply aggregating was a much better approach. The top bit of code was perfect.  The 2nd runs, but it leaves out a days - meaning there are day long gaps in the sequence from start to end for each cougar.  Any thoughts?  As indicated above, my thought was to merge the existing data frame with a newly created sequence of days.

Comment: @B.Davis You are correct that the second part misses a few days because it only creates values for days where observations from at least one subject occurred. Your idea of merging with a complete list of dates sounds like a good one.

Comment: Follow up question.  When applying the 'aggregate' function to my larger data set which has additional columns that are not used in the formula, how can I include them in the new (aggregated) data table?  The table that results only included columns in the formula and I did not see an all = T or something similar in the help file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @B.Davis Unfortunately, having other columns where the `max` function is not appropriate makes things more difficult. I've updated my answer with a different subsetting method that will preserve all other columns.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a bunch.  Very creative, informative, and helpful.  Cheers!